# Replace cells containing zero with blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large amount of data A4:EW8000+ that I want to replace cells containing a zero with a blank cell. Formatting the cells is not an option as I need to retain the current format. I'm looking for the fastest way to replace zeros with blank cells.

I can do this with looping but its very slow. Below code:

```
Sub clearzero() 
Dim rng As Range 
For Each rng In Range("A1:EW10000")
    If rng.Value = 0 Then 
        rng.Value = "" 
    End If 
Next 
End Sub
```

Is there an easy way I can do this without looping?

I tried the below code, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. It hangs Excel for a while (not responding) then it loops through the range and blanks every cell.

```
Sub RemoveZero()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Const StartRow As Long = 2
  LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="0", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
  With Range("B:EW")
     .Value = Range("B:EW").Value
     .Replace "0", "0", xlWhole, , False
     On Error Resume Next
     .SpecialCells(xlConstants).Value = ""
     .SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Value = 0
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: another option: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Hide-or-display-zero-values-6ff815ca-e075-4f0b-adbe-728e1559b404

Answer (score 5):

This is all the VBA you need to automate the replacements:

```
[a4:ew10000].Replace 0, "", 1
```

.

**UPDATE**

While the above is concise, the following is likely the fastest way possible. It takes less than a quarter of a second on my computer for your entire range:

```
Sub RemoveZero()

    Dim i&, j&, v, r As Range

    Set r = [a4:ew10000]
    v = r.Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            If Len(v(i, j)) Then
                If v(i, j) = 0 Then r(i, j) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think `LookAt:=xlWhole` would be very necessary in an operation like this.

Comment: Depends on what the OP wants. I read it differently but on second reading, it seems likely he only wants to replace when `0` is the entire value. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes. I re-read it too and can see where your thinking came from because the OP doesn't *explicitly* state either way.

Comment: @ExcelHero I tried `[a4:ew10000].Replace 0, "", 1` and it performs the task requested but it hangs up excel for a ~30 seconds then performs the task which takes about ~2 minutes total.

Comment: I only want to replace the entire value of zero. I have some values of 0.0001234 that I want to maintain.

Comment: @ExcelHero Just tried your updated code. It got to row EW52 and hung up excel for ~1 min, then debug error 13: mismatch highlighting `If Len(v(i, j)) Then` BUT it did remove all zeros in the desired range

Comment: What's is the value of v(i, j) when it breaks? Something very odd there.

Comment: Don't wish to appear disparaging but with A4:EW10000 filled with `RANDBETWEEN(0, 9)` (values only), a quarter-second seems a little optimistic.

Comment: It did not seem likely that zeroes would represent 10% of the data.

Comment: @KyleL Do you have a lot of formulas in the workbook and Calculation set to Automatic?

Comment: @Excelhero - I cant send this document as the information is confidential. Id have to omit almost the entire workbook. Theres 3 formulas in the workbook but not on the sheet i'm omitting zeros from, calculation is set to auto. We're pretty much at a stalemate here because I cant send you my document with the data intact.  Sorry for being a royal pain lol

Comment: @ExcelHero - omiting the Zero's is more me just being a pain in the a - So lets try and go about this a different way. I have meetings for the rest of the day but Ill shoot you an email when I can with a sample document and maybe we can work something out. I have your email from the last time you helped me.

Comment: Replace `If Len(v(i, j)) Then` with `If Not IsEmpty(v(i, j)) Then` and it will be even faster.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that sometimes it is actually more expedient to cycle through the columns on bulk replace operations like this.

```
dim c as long
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        for c = 1 to .columns.count
            with .columns(c)
                .replace what:=0, replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlWhole
            end with
        next c
    end with
end with
```

Splitting the overall scope into several smaller operations can improve overall performance. My own experience with this is on somewhat larger data blocks (e.g. 142 columns × ~250K rows) and replacing NULL from an SQL feed not zeroes but this should help.

Comment: `lookat:=xlWhole` is key. I was using `xlPart` and turning 40s into 4. =(

Comment: @Jeeped I would use `Empty` instead of `vbNullString` to get really empty cell. The most annoying "feature" of `vbNullString` cells for me has always been than they are added to count when column / range of cells is selected, so that I can't quickly see how many elements really have any value.

Comment: vbNullString is not the same as `""` and creates a truly blank cell. It is not included in either COUNT or COUNTA.