# How do I replace '0' values with blank cells?

Tags: excel

[image]

Some fields return a zero value due to how the database deals with transactions that have been created, but ultimately no sale has been made. How do i change these to blank cells instead?

Using Excel 2016

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833934/replace-cells-containing-zero-with-blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace cells containing zero with blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833934/replace-cells-containing-zero-with-blank)

Comment: Do you want to change the actual data to empty cells, or just format to hide the 0 and show it as empty?

Comment: format to hide the 0, and show as empty. The 0 figure is of no importance and only congests the table.

Comment: @narn The code given in the possible duplicate may work, but there is no real explanation of where you place it in the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to Ctrl + F, select the Replace tab.

Find what: 0
Replace with:

Leave the Replace with blank.

You can also select options in case you want to edit in specific sheets, columns, etc.

Comment: So it's in a Pivot table? Do you want to keep it there or just work with the data in a different spreadsheet?

Comment: Would like to keep it there, the person who receives the report is happy with it, but the '0's' really bother me. I have researched a fair bit, and cannot find any obvious solutions. I would have thought it was a fairly easy fix though.

Comment: Well unfortunately you can't change value cells that are part of a Pivot Table. You'd have to copy the data to a different worksheet, alter it, and then modify the values in the pivot table to pull from there.

Comment: Sure. Have you considered using Filters instead of Pivot? For your spreadsheet, it looks to be a good alternative.